# How prove that $\max(|f(1)|,|f(2)|,|f(3)|,|f(4)|)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ if $f(x) = \cos(Ax)+\cos(Bx)$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

Let $ A, B$ be real numbers and $ f(x) =\cos(Ax) + \cos(Bx)$. How prove that
$ \max(|f(1)|,|f(2)|,|f(3)|,|f(4)|)\geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I think there is still a typo... $f(x) \color{red}{=} \cos Ax + \cos Bx$

Comment: Jonas, why down it?

Comment: @piteer: Please confirm that the correction Surb indicated is correct, and consider adding more context to improve your question.

Comment: From my point of view, the question is well stated... piteer did not add his work...

Comment: Yes, the adjustment is correct

Comment: Maybe you can try to use something like
$a+b+c+d \geq 2 \Rightarrow \max\{a,b,c,d\} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for any $a,b,c,d \geq 0$

Comment: Is $|f(1)|+|f(2)|+|f(3)|+|f(4)|>2$???? Mayby $|f(1)|+|f(2)|+|f(3)|+|f(4)|>8$?

Comment: @piteer: That last inequality is always false, for any choice of $A$ and $B$.   $f(x)\leq 2$ for all $x$.

Comment: @piteer My comment is just referring to a classical average argument: if $m$ is the average of $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ then there must be some $x_i$ such that $x_i \geq m$. (actually you don't even need them to be positive).

Comment: It is a classical measure argument, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Briggs' formulas, $\cos(Ax)+\cos(Bx) = 2\cos(Cx)\cos(Dx)$, where $C=\frac{A+B}{2}$ and $D=\frac{A-B}{2}$. By the multiplication formula for the cosine function (aka Chebyshev polynomials of the first type) everything just depends on $\cos(C)=\cos(u)$ and $\cos(D)=\cos(v)$. The set:
$$ S=\left\{x\in[0,2\pi]:|\cos x|\geq \frac{1}{2}\right\} \tag{1}$$
is the union of the intervals:
$$ S=\left[0,\frac{\pi}{3}\right]\cup\left[\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{4\pi}{3}\right]\cup\left[\frac{5\pi}{3},2\pi\right]$$
and hence it has relative measure $\frac{2}{3}$ with respect to $[0,2\pi]$. We just need to show that for any choice of $P=(u,v)\in\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{T}$ at least one point among $P,2P,3P,4P$ belongs to $S\times S$.

For any $\{E,F,G\}\subset\{1,2,3,4\}$ we have:
$$\max(|\cos Eu|,|\cos Fu|,|\cos Gu|)\geq\frac{1}{2},$$
[image: A colorful proof]

(proof without words), so we can choose $\{G,H\}\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that both $|\cos Gu|$ and $|\cos Hu|$ are greater or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. Then for some $I\in\{G,H\}$ we have $|\cos Iv|\geq\frac{1}{2}$, hence we have found a point $x\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ in which the absolute value of $2\cos(Cx)\cos(Dx)$ is greater or equal to $2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$, as wanted.

This is the (very irregular) graphics of $\max(|f(1)|,|f(2)|,|f(3)|,|f(4)|)$ as a function of $A$ and $B$:

[image: Graphics of $\max_{x\in\{1,2,3,4\}}|f_{A,B}(x)|$]